# RDS Oracle : Why does it take so long to create a table?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, rds

I am creating a tables with 370+ columns. 

When I execute a query to create the table in SQL Developer, it keeps on running and never finishes.

The query looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "AAAA"."TABLEA" 
(500+ columns)
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 7340032 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "ABCDE" ;
```

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: My best guess is the tablespace is out of free space and it's waiting on that.  To find out the real reason you'll want to look at the session and see what event it's waiting on.  Run this query: `select event, blocking_session, gv$session.* from gv$session;`.  You may need to run it a few times to sample the different events, they can change every second.  If the session is waiting on someone else it will show up in the column `blocking_session`.

Comment: @JonHeller For some reason, the query you suggested itself keeps on running and does not give any output...

Comment: Sounds like something is seriously wrong with this database.  If you can't even look at the sessions troubleshooting is going to be tough.  Maybe you'll need to look for operating system problems or try restarting the database.

Comment: All queries work in SQLPlus, but not in SQL Developer. Maybe this could be client software or Amazon RDS specific problem...

Comment: There might be a problem with a data dictionary query.  Programs like SQL Developer typically run some queries in the background to gather metadata about the results.  Maybe those background queries are freezing.  Try running the queries in SQL Developer and then do the troubleshooting in SQL*Plus.  Try to find the slow-running query with something like `select sql_text, elapsed_time from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`.

Comment: Is is possible to prevent SQL developer from executing the query?
It seems SQL developer executes such query on startup.

Comment: Possibly.  There might be some sort of configuration option to limit the background queries.  But you'd need to figure out what the query is first.  And it might be easier to try to fix that query than to stop it.  I assume it's a data dictionary query so you might want to try gathering dictionary and fixed object stats with `begin dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats; end;` and `begin dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats; end;`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it.